# How to properly manage large amount of images in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my application i display quite a large amount of images approximately 200, sooner or later I'm getting memory warning but I don't know what to do next

I have a subclass of UIImageView that downloads images asynchronously and displays them like this

```
self.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] autorelease];
```

How and when should I clean up the memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im assuming you only have one image on the screen at a time?

Comment: No once all images are downloaded they are all on the screen

Comment: Im assuming then that you are using a scroll view. You might want to consider putting the pictures that are not on the screen in a cash folder.

Comment: Could you point to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try use a small images in list. On click on small image, show a large image. Try use optimization methods for this case:)

Answer (score 0):

> once all images are downloaded they are all on the screen

Composite what you can (into one image), ideally on the server side so you have less to download, load into memory, and render on the client side.

As well, make sure the images are the size you will draw them at. This can save a lot of memory and also processing (unless you are using shoddy or fast rescaling).

There's a lot of context missing in your post. If a solution were universal and trivial, would you not assume there's a good chance it's already being used by the system's frameworks?